# Website with Apps and SE rankings

Tags: search-engines, google-ranking

Currently I have a website that is very popular for related search terms, with very little bounce rates and it is ranking very well. It is an ecommerce site.

I want to offer apps for my regular users so that I can send notifications and other benefits that come with having an App such as being able to create orders without going through the website.

The thing is because the users are coming to the site via search engines, even though they may or may not now the URL they'll just type in the website's name and click on it from the organic results, this helps my website's ranking and popularity.

When I introduce the App, the above i.e. going through search engine will happen a lot less because there won't be any need to anymore. How is that going to affect my ranking in search engines or will it?

Comment: I do think you'll lose some ranking from users not typing your brand into Google as much. I don't know what SEO boost you'll get from users using your app to offset the ranking loss. This is a great question.

Comment: I hope it's not a trade off, I'd prefer somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. But I have to ask, how is your mobile traffic? As you may know, Google is now crawling mobile first, so in order to succeed, you must have a mobile-friendly solution, and an app is a great way to accomplish this. Google's mobile traffic makes up for 50% of all Google's search traffic, and not to mention, mobile apps can also show up in Google search results. I found this out while searching for weather using chrome on an android device.

Additionally, understanding the way users are using mobile is extremely important. The mobile app is a total usability winner: 89% of mobile media time is spent on apps, and the remaining 11% is spent on the mobile web via mobile search engines & mobile sites.

I recommend trying out [Google's mobile-Friendly Test](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/).  This will help you know where you stand w/ mobile. Although having a mobile friendly website is usually the easier and more cost effective way to go - I definitely recommend making a mobile app, if you have the means, based on the desired benefits of having a mobile app.

Lastly, this should not have a negative effect on your traffic at all. The mobile version of your site would simply have an option at the bottom of the screen to download the app from the app store. A user can opt to click it to download, or close it. I would imagine that being listed in the app store would only bring more users, though it's hard to say.